# Encryption/Decryption on multiple users using RSA?

Tags: rsa

Supposing I have Alice that is the RA, Bob (who is a user) and Kate (who is also a user). For now I use RSA. Alice sends a message to Bob. Alice also sends a message to Kate. Bob and Kate exchange their messages as they took them from Alice (without decrypting them and encrypting them) using the public key of Alice. My question is how can Bob and Kate decrypt the messages using the public key of Alice? Is there any other protocol that should I use when I have 1 RA, and many users, and I want the users to decrypt the messages they got from the RA (without decrypting and encrypting in the mean time)? What I am trying to do here is Bob to get the message of Kate and do some checking, and also Kate get the message of Bob and do some checking.

Thank you

Comment: I do not know, if I have confused you. I think is it clear what I am trying to achieve...

Comment: If you use public key crypto, then the sender A encrypts message with public key of receiver B, not the other way around.

Comment: What protocol shhould I use in order to achieve what I describe on my question? Does Attribute Based Encryption (ABE) work in this case? Thank you..

Comment: Proxy re-encryption?

Comment: The whole work is done using wireless nodes on ns3...

Comment: I cannot find how proxy re-encryption will work here, since I want the initial message not to be changed in order to compare it with what the other has received